# Oozie whitelisted resource managers causing whitelist error

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera, oozie

I have the following resource manager defined in my job.properties:

```
resourceManager=nn1:8032, nn2:8032, yarnrm
```

When I attempt to run the job I receive an error stating my resource manager nodes are not in my whitelist, although they are the exact same:

```
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: HadoopAccessorException: E0900: JobTracker [nn1:8032, nn2:8032, yarnrm] not allowed, not in Oozie's whitelist. Allowed values are: [nn1:8032, nn2:8032, yarnrm]
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:443)
```

I have attempted to alter the references to the resource managers to:

```
resourceManager=nn1:8032,nn2:8032,yarnrm
```

and see the same error.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: The "Allowed values" message gives you a **list** of 3 **possible** values. Pick one. And you'd better pick the HA alias, by the way.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have stated that I have attempted to use the three possible values but the error still remains.

Comment: Not sure we are on the same line. Did you try `resourceManager=yarnrm
`?

Comment: I have tried the following permutations: `resourceManager=yarnrm` , `resourceManager=nn1:8032` , `resourceManager=nn2:8032` , `resourceManager=nn1:8032,nn2:8032,yarnrm` all created the same error, with different error text as expected.

Comment: OK. How do you use that "parameter" in your workflow HML?

Comment: Hi in the workflow.xml I have it defined as so:  `<workflow-app name="spark-pi-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
  <start to='spark-pi'/>
  <action name='spark-pi'>
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <master>yarn</master>
      <mode>cluster</mode>
`

Comment: Have a look at https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Running-Oozie/td-p/9020 about how to fix possible lousy config set by Cloudera Manager

Comment: To inspect the actual config generated by CM for the Oozie server, connect to the node running Oozie and run `sudo find /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/ -name oozie-site.xml` then inspect the file and look for the "whitelist" stuff. It should match the following properties in `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` : `yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id` and `yarn.resourcemanager.address.*` (for a HA cluster)

Comment: Now, if you don't have a HA cluster... it should match `yarn.resourcemanager.address` and nothing else. Even better, remove the "whitelist" stuff.